Running erlang distributed application using rebar3
I am new to rebar3. I have a simple chat app which consists of two modules namely; my_server and my_client. in ordinar case, I can run the server module by openning the terminal and type:
my_server:start_link().

and for the client to talk to the server I can do for example
my_client:login(Somename).

Now, I build and compiled the application with rebar3 using below commands
rebar3 new app chat

and then,
rebar3 compile

this produced a folder as below:
     chat ---
             _build
             src
             .gitignore
             LICENSE
             README
             rebar.config    

and the beam files are located in \chat\_build\default\lib\chat\ebin
Here, I can start the app by open the terminal at the chat folder and using:
rebar3 shell --sname server

the server module my_server starts with the application started because I set it as a child process.
Now, I tried to do something like
my_client:login(Somename)

by opening the terminal at the application folder chat  but I got error that my_client:login is undefended. However, when I  navigate to the beam files and open the terminal there it works fine. It seems that the application can't fetch the module my_client.
My question is how to do
my_client:login(Somename)

without navigating to the beam files?

If you check the documentation for rebar shell command:
http://rebar3.org/docs/commands/#shell
It says you can specify a comma separated list of applications to start using the "--apps" option.
Personally I do prefer starting my applications using the Erlang shell and then I give it an extra application folder using the -pa option like this:
erl +K true +P 134217727 -pa _build/default/lib/*/ebin -sname my_server -s my_server_app

+K enables kernel_poll for faster IO and +P sets the maximum number of allowed processes.
